# Bokeh share variable between two callbacks

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

In bokeh the Reset tool doesn't work intuitively when used on a plot that is showing data off an empty fillable ColumnDataSource. It overrides the width and height of the plot with the default width and height.

While trying to get around it with a simple button interaction, I got blocked by the apparent necessity to transfer a variable between two callbacks.

In the following code, the plot displays what is in "source1", which is filled with items from "source2" during the "radiogroup" callback.

Is there a way to use the "var y" and "var x" declared in "callback" inside "callback2" ? If I pass "source1" as an argument to "callback2" it won't work because it will pass the empty source.

I also tried to pass "button" as an argument to "callback" and write the button callback inside the "callback" code, but couldn't find a way to make it work.

```
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, RadioGroup, Button, VBox
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

x0 = range(10)
x1 = range(100)
y0 = [i for i in x0]
y1 = [i*2 for i in x1][::-1]


fig=Figure(height=250,width=800)

source1=ColumnDataSource(data={"x":[],"y":[]})
source2=ColumnDataSource(data={"x0":x0,"x1":x1,"y0":y0,"y1":y1})

p = fig.line(x='x',y='y',source=source1)

callback=CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1,s2=source2,px=fig.x_range,py=fig.y_range),  code="""
    var d1 = s1.get("data");
    var d2 = s2.get("data");
    var val = cb_obj.active;

    d1["y"] = [];
    d1["x"] = [];
    var y = d2["y"+val];
    var x = d2["x"+val];

    var min = Math.min( ...y );
    var max = Math.max( ...y );

    py.set("start",min);
    py.set("end",max);

    var min = Math.min( ...x );
    var max = Math.max( ...x );

    px.set("start",min);
    px.set("end",max);

    for(i=0;i<=y.length;i++){
        d1["y"].push(d2["y"+val][i]);
        d1["x"].push(d2["x"+val][i]);
    }

    s1.trigger("change");
    """)

callback2=CustomJS(args=dict(px=fig.x_range,py=fig.y_range), code="""   
    var min = Math.min( ...y );
    var max = Math.max( ...y );

    py.set("start",min);
    py.set("end",max);

    var min = Math.min( ...x );
    var max = Math.max( ...x );

    px.set("start",min);
    px.set("end",max);

    s1.trigger("click")
    """)


radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels=['First plot','Second plot'],active=0,callback=callback)
radiobox = VBox(radiogroup,width=100)
button = Button(label='Reset axes',button_type='success',callback=callback2)
buttonbox = VBox(button,width=100)

grid = gridplot([[radiobox,buttonbox],[fig]])

outfile=open('TEST.html','w')
outfile.write(file_html(grid,CDN,'Reset'))
outfile.close()
```

**EDIT:** 
Feeling a bit silly that I found a solution so fast after asking even though I searched and tried for a long time before posting. But here is a workaround, I just had to pass the radiogroup as an argument in "callback2" to fill "var val" and then refill "source1".

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(s1=source1,s2=source2,px=fig.x_range,py=fig.y_range),  code="""
    var d1 = s1.get("data");
    var d2 = s2.get("data");
    var val = cb_obj.active;

    d1["y"] = [];
    d1["x"] = [];
    var y = d2["y"+val];
    var x = d2["x"+val];

    var min = Math.min( ...y );
    var max = Math.max( ...y );

    py.set("start",min);
    py.set("end",max);

    var min = Math.min( ...x );
    var max = Math.max( ...x );

    px.set("start",min);
    px.set("end",max);

    for(i=0;i<=y.length;i++){
        d1["y"].push(d2["y"+val][i]);
        d1["x"].push(d2["x"+val][i]);
    }

    s1.trigger("change");
    """)


radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels=['First plot','Second plot'],active=0,callback=callback)
radiobox = VBox(radiogroup,width=100)

callback2=CustomJS(args=dict(radiogroup=radiogroup,s1=source1,s2=source2,px=fig.x_range,py=fig.y_range), code="""   
    var d1 = s1.get("data");
    var d2 = s2.get("data");
    var val = radiogroup.active;

    d1["y"] = [];
    d1["x"] = [];
    var y = d2["y"+val];
    var x = d2["x"+val];

    var min = Math.min( ...y );
    var max = Math.max( ...y );

    py.set("start",min);
    py.set("end",max);

    var min = Math.min( ...x );
    var max = Math.max( ...x );

    px.set("start",min);
    px.set("end",max);

    for(i=0;i<=y.length;i++){
        d1["y"].push(d2["y"+val][i]);
        d1["x"].push(d2["x"+val][i]);
    }

    s1.trigger("click")
    """)

button = Button(label='Reset axes',button_type='success',callback=callback2)
buttonbox = VBox(button,width=100)
```

**EDIT 2:** The Reset can in fact work as the "Reset axes" button above. The Reset tool resets the figure size to `plot_width` and `plot_height`, which are 600 by default. I used `width` and `height` to declare my figure and that is why the reset tool would reset to a 600x600 figure.

Anyhow the question still holds for passing variables between two callbacks. If I declare "var Z = 0;" in "callback" is there any way to use Z in "callback2" ?